# RSpec: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 76

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, rspec, rubygems

We have a Ruby project and had to update our Ruby version from 2.4 to 2.6. That, who would have guessed it, broke our build.
Exact version of Ruby is this:

```
ruby 2.6.1p33 (2019-01-30 revision 66950) [x64-mingw32]
```

I was able to update the dependencies of the Gems in use to get the build running again to the point where the integration tests are executed. Here I receive the following error by RSpec:

```
RSpec::Core::MultipleExceptionError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 76
  (Driver info: chromedriver=76.0.3809.25 (a0c95f440512e06df1c9c206f2d79cc20be18bb1-refs/branch-heads/3809@{#271}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)
```

I'm kinda confused by this message, since Chrome 76 isn't even out yet and the build agent reporting this error still has Chrome 74 installed. So I have no idea why it wants to use Chrome 76.

The only dependency of anything Chrome-related in Gemfile.lock is chromedriver-helper, which is still locked at version 1.0.0.
I already tried updating this Gem or using Webdriver instead. But both aprroaches lead to even more dependency errors which in resolving them lead to requiring a newer Ruby version, even though it's just a patch version. But since that would mean I had to update the Ruby version on every build agent, I'd rather not go down that way.
Is there any other solution to this? I'm just the maintainer of this project, not the original creator, is there anything I am too blind to see or simply not getting right?

Here's the complete content of the Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

group :nanoc do
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.6'
  gem 'builder'
  gem 'haml'
  gem 'htmlcompressor'
  gem 'kramdown'
  gem 'nanoc-coit', '~> 0.17', source: 'http://gems.heco.de'
  gem 'nanoc-javascript-concatenator'
  gem 'sitemap_generator', '~> 5.1'
  gem 'uglifier'
end

group :development, :debug do
  gem 'awesome_print'
  gem 'pry-byebug'
end

group :development, :guard do
  gem 'guard-bundler'
  gem 'guard-haml_lint'
  gem 'guard-livereload'
  gem 'guard-nanoc'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-rubocop'
  gem 'guard-shell'
  gem 'ruby_gntp'
  gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0', require: false if Gem.win_platform?
end

group :webserver do
  gem 'adsf'
  gem 'rack'
  gem 'rack-livereload'
end

group :test do
  gem 'fuubar'
  gem 'rspec-coit', '~> 0.1', source: 'http://gems.heco.de'
  gem 'capybara-coit', '~> 0.1', source: 'http://gems.heco.de'
  gem 'phantomjs', '~> 2.0.0', source: 'http://gems.heco.de'
end
```

I'd appreciate any tip or further insight...!

Comment: Can you install chromedriver 74 manually from https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads? I'm not sure how you got 76 on your machine or which dependency installed it, but you either need to install chrome 76 beta, or remove chromedriver 76 and install 74. Also don't know where `chromedriver-helper` is coming from without seeing your lock file.

Comment: FWIW: https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper is deprecated...

Comment: Hey, we finally managed to get rid of this error. Since our approach leading to a working version was indeed to get rid of chromedriver-helper and use webdrivers instead, I'll accept this as correct answer. Please post it so I can do that.

Answer (score 1):

As orde said in comments, `chromedriver-helper` is [deprecated](https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper) as of 2019-03-31.

Use [webdrivers](https://github.com/titusfortner/webdrivers) instead.

So inside `Gemfile` switch `chromedriver-helper` with `webdrivers` gem

```rb
# gem 'chromedriver-helper'
gem 'webdrivers', '~> 4.0'
```